# Running flash files on Android 8

Tags: adobe-flash

I have been running flash files and sites on Android 6 very smoothly using Dolphin video or dolphin browser. After upgrading into Android 8, none of these apps are running well: Dolphin browser is unable to install from google play or from APK, and Dolphin video is unable to work porperly.

Does anyone have any solution for flash files?

Comment: Adobe stopped flash support on Android long time ago. May be you installed the old flash app manually on your old phone? However using this old flash app is like inviting everybody on the net to install malware on your system.

Comment: I was using some official apps from google play store !

Answer (score 0):

It's a 2 step workaround solution :
Go to the play store & install this version of [Puffin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree)

Open this [website](http://flashplayer.fullstacks.net/).
Browse for your local file, upload it & let it play.